# is it possible to install scapy on openWRT

Tags: scapy, openwrt, sniffing

I want to install scapy and wireshrk for python 2.7(already present in openWRT) in an ARM system having openWRT? Is there a package easy to install scapy in openWRT?

Comment: https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata_lede17_1/scapy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about `wireshark`, but it is possible for `scapy`. Follow these steps:

```
opkg update
opkg upgrade tar wget
opkg install python tcpdump unzip
wget http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapy-latest.tar.gz
tar -xvf scapy-latest.tar.gz
cd scapy*
python setup.py install
cd ..
rm -rf scapy*
```

It worked for me, with my `Arduino Yun`.

Comment: Dead link on your `wget` .

Answer (score 1):

As of today, `scapy` is available on the **repositories**:

```
# opkg update
# opkg install scapy
```